# Which Perl module 'explains' an expression provided on the command line?

Tags: perl, parentheses

I forgot the module name that "explains" the expression provided on the command line. 
By "explain", I mean add omitted parentheses.

As I remember, it is used like:

```
perl -MSomeModule "$x/$y*$z"
```

The result should be:

```
($x/$y)*$z
```

Do you know what the name of the module is?

Comment: Since there is a real answer, I disagree with "not a real question" close votes

Comment: People suck for downvoting this. It's a perfectly good question (and the answer is `B::Deparse` as posted below.)

Answer (score 14):

```
> perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e '$x/$y*$z'
(($x / $y) * $z);
-e syntax OK
```

How's that?